# call a function from javascript in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How do i call a function in jquery that i have written? The following code that I tried is not working.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        function afunction() {
            alert("me");
        }
    });
</script>

<script>
    afunction();
</script>
```

Comment: Do you understand what `$(function() {})` line does?

Comment: You're Limiting Scope of `afunction` by defining it inside `$(function().. `.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is simply a JavaScript library. You can mix regular JavaScript in without requiring everything use the jQuery `$()`. Because of function scope, wrapping your function in the `$(document).ready` function will make it unavailable to be called outside of the `ready` function.

Try changing your code to this:

```
function afunction() {
        alert("me");
}
```

If you need to define a function inside of a jQuery function or event handler, that's fine too. Although it's been pointed out that you can't call this function outside of the `ready` event handler, I would like to demonstrate that jQuery and JavaScript are not separate and can be mixed. For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function afunction() {
        alert("me");
    }

    afunction();

});
```

Comment: Again!! You're Limiting Scope of `afunction` by defining it inside `$(document).ready(function())..`. For More see: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGsdf/).

Comment: I am trying to demonstrate how a regular JavaScript function can be defined within a jQuery function. Many people misunderstand jQuery and think that it is somehow 'separate' from JavaScript.

Comment: I've updated the answer to better explain how JavaScript and jQuery can work together.

Comment: Now It seems to be working. But I've not casted the downvote. Will Upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `$(function()` is another form of `$(document).ready()`.

As Vedant mentioned, usually you cannot call a function (JS/jQuery) from outside the function in which it is defined.

You should probably declare `function afunction()` outside of `$(function()` method, alternatively you could declare it as 
    `global function afunction()` for universal access.

Answer (score 0):

okay. Here is What I Meant.

You're Creating A function inside a `self executing anonymus function` ie. `$(document).ready()` or `$(function()...`.

So your function is in local scope of that function. Simply Means You cant access that in outside of that function.

So to make it accessible just make it global.

In JavaScript `window` is global object. So to make your function global, use that object as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function afunction() {
        alert("me");
    }

    window.afunction=afunction;  //NOTE THIS, IT IS IMPORTANT.

});
```

Now you can access it elsewhere in your JS.

Here is working

## [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/EGsdf/3/)

Hope it'll help you! cheers :)..